# placeholder for select in vuejs 2.0.0

Tags: javascript, select, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a webapp using [vuejs 2.0](https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html). I have created simple select input using following code:

```
  <select v-model="age">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Age</option>
    <option value="1"> 1 Year</option>
    <option value="11"> 11 Year</option>
  </select>
```

and I have this in `data` of my Vue component:

```
data () {
  return {
    age: "",
  }
},
watch: {      
  age: function (newAge) {
    console.log("log here")
  }
```

But I start to get this error when adding default value for select:

> ERROR in ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler.js?id=data-v-5cf0d7e0!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/cde.vue
>   template syntax error :
>   inline selected attributes on  will be ignored when using v-model. Declare initial values in the component's data option instead.
>
> @ ./src/components/cde.vue 10:23-151
>
> @ ./~/babel-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?
>   type=script&index=0!./src/views/abcView.vue
>   @ ./src/views/abcView.vue
>
> @ ./src/router/index.js
>
> @ ./src/app.js
>
> @ ./src/client-entry.js
>
> @ multi app

I tried to give default value in the data section of the component as well, but then nothing happened. I tried `v-bind` also but then watchers stopped working on age variable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vjvMp/668/ Seems to work fine

Comment: Yes, it worked when I removed selected from the default options. Thanks @haim770

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The only thing needed to work this was remove `selected` from default `option`:

```
 <select v-model="age">
    <option value="" disabled hidden>Select Age</option>
    .....
  </select>
```

Comment: Yes, if you want something to be pre-selected, you have to set the value like `this.age="1"`, which results in "1 Year" to be selected automatically when the DOM renders.

Answer (score 53):

For others who may be landing on this question, there was an additional step for me to get the default option to appear. In my case, the `v-model` I was binding to was returning `null` and rather than an empty string. This meant that the default option was never selected once Vue bindings kicked in.

To solve for this, simple bind the `value` property of your default option to `null`:

```
<select v-model="age">
  <option :value="null" disabled>Select Age</option>
  ...
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Logme0m/1/

Comment: Plus: add disabled, and hidden properties can hide the placeholder from the option list. e.g. <option :value="null" disabled hidden>Select Age</option>

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 16):

For placeholder, you need to set the value attribute with the same value as in defined as initial value in your state.

Change your disabled option with

```
<option value="null" disabled selected hidden>Select Age</option>
```

and in state do something like this

```
data () {enter code here
  return {
    age: null,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To build upon Shivam Bisht, In case you can't access your default value.
Just add value="undefined" to your placeholder option tag.

Placeholder text

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      param: undefined,
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <select v-model="param">
    <option value="undefined" disabled>Placeholder text</option>
    <option value="1">Dutch woman are beautiful.</option>
    <option value="11">German Men are slow.</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me but I put in :value="undefined", without needing assign anything in the data.

Answer (score 3):

To add up on other answers, as they all seem to be correct at a specific condition:
It depends on the data type expected by your v-model variable, for example if it is expecting an integer passing :value="null" or :value="undefined" would work, but if it is expecting an object for example, then you need to pass :value="{}".

```
//Example: data/v-model expects integer
<select v-model="param">
   <option :value="undefined" disabled>Placeholder text</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
</select>

//Example: data/v-model expects object
<select v-model="param">
   <option :value="{}" disabled>Placeholder text</option>
   <option
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
        :value="item"
      >
        {{ item.propery }}
   </option>
</select>
```

For a string null or undefined values should work, but you could also just define a placeholder in you data object.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I got it working:

```
<select v-model="selectedTemplate" class="btn btn-default">
   <option v-for="template in templates" v-bind:value="template.tasks"}{{template.name}}</option>
   <option :value="this.selectedTemplate" disabled hidden>Select a template</option>
</select>
```

The key being the `:value=this.selectedtemplate` in the disabled hidden option.

Comment: this method doesn't work. all when selecting any other value other than the default, the state of the selectbox does't change

Comment: @ktscript it works in my application. Perhaps you forgot the v-bind:value in your list?

Comment: no, I didn't forget, your code is looping for me. but perhaps the reason should be found in my code.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This worked when included in a v-for